# Spring Boot and Camel Mail SSL config

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

Am trying to configure Spring Boot with Camel so that am able to send mails using smtps.
I have simple route

```
@Component
public class EmailRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  public static final String IN = "seda://email";

  public static final String OUT = "smtps://myhost:465?myuser&password=mypass&debugMode=true";

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(IN).to(OUT);
  }
```

When I send something using this route am getting error :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host : myhost    
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have pem file cert ( without keys , just cert ) and I have imported it to the jks keychain file

added a method to the EmailRoute class for creating SSLContextParameters params

```
private SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters(){
    KeyStoreParameters store = new KeyStoreParameters();
    store.setResource("pathToJskFile/cert.jks");
    store.setPassword("123456");

    TrustManagersParameters trust = new TrustManagersParameters();
    trust.setKeyStore(store);

    SSLContextParameters parameters = new SSLContextParameters();
    parameters.setTrustManagers(trust);

    return parameters;
  }
```

Not sure now how to connect does two using camel and spring boot , as the example from http://camel.apache.org/mail.html with registry is not 100% clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can likely use Spring Boot to register the `SSLContextParameters` in its registry with the `@Bean`.

Make the method public and add the `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
public SSLContextParameters myMailSslContextParameters() {
```

And then tell Camel smtp endpoint to use this using the `#` lookup syntax:

```
smtps://myhost:465?myuser&password=mypass&debugMode=true&sslContextParameters=#myMailSslContextParameters
```

Notice how the name of the method is the name you use for lookup.

Comment: Thx, it works!
Had to add also 
mail.smtp.auth=true and mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
sending to anyone works but not to gmail ( strange , must be a problem with my mail server )